# sas not do sum of all obeservation

Tags: sas

i have a dataset name censusdata with  11346 observation in last some observationare blank data.we have to find total population variable name t_p.

i am using this code:

```
data q1(keep=t_p count);
set censusdata;
array num(*) t_p;
retain count;
do i=1 to dim(num);
if t_p = i then count=t_p;
else count+t_p;
end;
run;
```

problem is sas find sum of first 3236 observation then do sum of 3237 to 4683 observation and so on.they cannot do sum of all observation as we need.

we need sum of totalpopulation(t_p) & we need output dataset like this

totalpopulation=number

Comment: Can you post some sample data that shows what you input looks like and what output you want? Just a few observations should be enough.  It is hard to tell but it sounds like you want to take the sum of a variable over the whole table.  If so look at PROC SUMMARY.

Answer (score 0):

Sum the variable in a proc sql step:

```
proc sql;
    create table q1 as select
        sum(t_p) as total_pop
        from censusdata;
quit;
```